# Customers database design

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

We design this database to track our customer database but I feel it is little complicated design I feel it can be  more simple can someone give some advice for design?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to break email up to that point? Usually one customer provides one email. Otherwise, it looks good to me.

Comment: We did this because our customers are working for different places like accounting

Comment: Phone table is missing Phone Type. Actually, you dont need phone type table.
Just add a column `phone_type` and store H, M or O for the type.
For the email, one customer will have more than one email?

Comment: If there were an option to vote down comments, I would vote down Bhrugesh's suggestion.

Comment: yes Because here in Canada some accountants are working with different client and sometime had many email.I don't agree with one-to-many customer and emails because customer provide one email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If simplicity is the key point here, I'd suggest you collapse your customer-related address type information into a single table like so :

```
    customer_contact_details{
    customer_id MEDIUM_INT
    contact_type VARCHAR2(10)
    contact_details VARCHAR2(100)
    status BOOLEAN
    }
```

The contact_type field can then be tagged as `Home Phone,email,primary_email,work_phone,primary contact` depending on your needs. You can then have all such related contact information in a single table. Streamlines your schema and you need only a single join to make sense of the info.

Comment: It never hurts to have a `status` field on database entity tables so you can flag the entity as `enabled` or `disabled` or `active` etc. it helps to avoid having to delete rows or records from your db, breaking your relations. You can just flag the entity as `inactive` and preserve the fk relations in your db. In your specific case, a customer with several address types may choose to deactivate his current home address maybe because he moved or something. In that instance, you definitely don't want to lose the old address in favour of a new one, as there will already be references to the old 1

Comment: OK fine. I have problem say I have 2 customer with same phone number this will create data redundancy I can add phone extension or something to make it unique?

Comment: @aelnajjar Obviously you'll be indexing the table as appropriate. All I've shown here is the datamodel. To prevent redundancy, simply put a composite unique index on any combination of customer_id, contact_type and contact_details as suits your needs. 2 customers with the same phone number should not be a problem, they might be members of the same household. Why can't they share the same home phone number?

Comment: they can share phone number. one of the reasons to design it many to many "customer and phones" user can update it once but I could not come with good UI mock-up to until I see your suggestion and Create generic table to hold all type of contact phones,faxes,email or website. I add new photo of database diagram can you told me what do you think about it?

Comment: looks ok, but I'd set all the fields to not allow `null` values. There really isn't any need to permit nulls in this setup is there?

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on this diagram:

- Set primary keys on your many-to-many join tables (both columns should be the PK, presumably)
- I don't see "duplicate" phone numbers in a table as violating rules of normalization, rather, I see it as coincidence.  You wouldn't have a whole table for first names simply because two people were named "Joe" for example.  Also, imagine if two people share a phone number, then one of them gets a different number.  It's an easy operation to update one number if `phone` references `Customer` directly, but odd (to me) to insert a new `phone` and have multiple operations on the join table just to do the same thing.
- Same deal with `Email`.
- How will the app pick which phone or email to use if there are multiple choices?  Should a `default` bit or `ordinal` column be provided?
- Does a customer have many locations, many companies, or both?

Comment: thanks for email & phone point. for customer sometime they working in different location in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Another partial solution is to use a table of contacts: a CUSTOMER has CONTACTS (one to many); each CONTACT might have several PHONE numbers (and even then, you'd only need one mobile number, one home number, one work number and one fax number) but only one EMAIL address.